# How do I select an image to import it to manipulate with `cropper.js` plugin in angular?

Tags: angular, cropperjs

I intended to import an image to my angular application and manipulate it with `croppers.js` plugin.
I can address an image with relative address and image will be shown properly but when I import an image with file input type, my application can not detect the image and raises an error.

My codes are listed below:

`.html` file:

```
<div class="originalImage">
    <img #image [src]="imageSource" >
</div>
<div>
    <img [src]="imageDestination" class="editedImage">
</div>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="openInput()">Select File to Upload</button>
<input id="fileInput" hidden type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" name="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png">
```

`.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

@Component({
selector: 'app-pictures',
templateUrl: './pictures.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./pictures.component.scss']
})

export class PicturesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("image", {static: false})
    public imageElement: ElementRef;
    public imageSource: string;
    public imageDestination: string;
    private cropper: Cropper;

    constructor() {
        this.imageDestination = '';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imageSource = '/assets/images/greg-cohen-3928.jpg';
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.cropper = new Cropper(this.imageElement.nativeElement, {
        viewMode:2,
        zoomable: true,
        scalable: true,
        cropBoxResizable: true,
        });
        
    }

    public cropIt() {
        console.log('start-crop');

        const canvas = this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
        minWidth: 256,
        minHeight: 256,
        maxWidth: 4096,
        maxHeight: 4096,
        fillColor: '#f0f',
        imageSmoothingEnabled: true,
        imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
        });
        this.imageDestination = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    }

    public openInput(){ 
        document.getElementById("fileInput").click();
    }

    public fileChange(x){
        this.imageSource = x.target.files[0]; 
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `.ts` file I addressed an image with relative URL in `ngOnInit()` and it shows the image correctly.

The problem starts when I selected new image for editing but it didn't replace old image with the new one and raises below error in console:

`GET http://localhost:2281/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)`

I don't know how to import new image and replace it. what's your idea?

Comment: because you are assigning wrong source to `this.imageSource` you have to assign image dataURL. need to change your `fileChange` function

Comment: would you please show me How?

Comment: yeah sure look at the ans, which I have posted...

Answer (score 1):

you just have to change your `filechange` function to

```
 public fileChange(x) {
    if (x.target.files.length >= 1) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = f => {
        this.imageSource = f.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(x.target.files[0]); // calls onload
    }
  }
```

do let me know still you have a problem with import file..

Thanks

Comment: It raised an error : property Result does not exist on type EventTarget!

Comment: hey, sorry for late reply, can you please create stackblitz, because I am not getting any error so I need to see what exactly you have done?

Answer (score 0):

Change your file change function to

```
public fileChange(event: Event) {
       const file =  (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
       const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = () => {
       const preview = reader.result as string;
    }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

Comment: Error is gone but old image didn't replace with new one. I think I should not use relative path. I should use blob image url.

Comment: Because new Cropper is always passed the ref of this.imageElement which is never updated after change of image, update that ref also on image change

Comment: I created a function to renew the ref and called it in `fileChange()` function but nothing changed. Would you please explain more in my code?

Comment: I think the problem is ngAFterViewInit getting called before file change, and at that time as there is no image present in the view so imageElement ref is null. If you can separate the ngAfterViewINit into a separate function and call it after image change, it should resolve the issue

Comment: I did it but nothing changed! I think it is not the right solution for my project. I intended to use ngx-image-cropper plug in instead of cropperjs.

Answer (score 0):

Do this bro:

`.html`

```
<input type="file (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
<div class="img-container">
    <img #imageCropper [src]="imageSource" crossorigin alt="image cropper">
</div>
<img [src]="imageDestination" class="img-preview" alt="image result">
```

`.ts` (No need for the ngAfterViewInit):

```
export class YourComponent {
    @ViewChild('imageCropper', { static: false })
    imageElement: ElementRef;
    imageSource: any = 'assets/images/bankwide-recon-icon.jpg';
    imageDestination = '';
    cropper: Cropper;

    constructor(
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) { }

    fileChangeEvent(event) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = (e: any) => {
                this.imageSource = e.target.result;
                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // Haven't tried out without this line
                if (this.cropper) { // Haven't tried out without this if block
                    this.cropper.destroy();
                }
                this.cropper = new Cropper(this.imageElement.nativeElement, {
                    crop: () => {
                        const canvas = this.cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
                        this.imageDestination = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    }
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

and the `.css`:

```
@import "~cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css";

.img-container {
    width: 720px;
    height: 720px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #e99158;
}

.img-preview {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #e99158;
}
```

Please reach me if there's any problem